# Objective c : strange behaviour when masking layer with another layer and changing frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, calayer

```
UIBezierPath * path                 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointZero radius:80 startAngle:0 endAngle:(2 * M_PI) clockwise:YES];

CAShapeLayer * layer                = [CAShapeLayer new];
layer.strokeColor                   = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
layer.fillColor                     = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
layer.lineWidth                     = 10;
layer.strokeEnd                     = 1;
layer.position                      = self.view.center;
layer.lineCap                       = kCALineCapRound;
[layer setPath                      : path.CGPath];
[self.view.layer addSublayer        : layer];

CAGradientLayer * gradientLayer     = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.startPoint            = CGPointMake(0.0,0.5);
gradientLayer.endPoint              = CGPointMake(1.0,0.5);
gradientLayer.frame                 = self.view.frame;
NSArray *colors                     = @[(id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor,(id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor];
gradientLayer.colors                = colors;
[gradientLayer setMask              : layer];
[self.view.layer addSublayer        : gradientLayer];
```

What Im doing:

Adding CAShapeLayer to view.layer with a path to draw a circle.

Adding CAGradientLayer ( 3 colors ) to view.layer and setingMask to the CAShapeLayer.

Result: with and without mask

[image]

[image]

The problem :

If I change the frame of the gradient to be on top of the circle ( because I want to see the all the colors on the circle ) its moves the circle as well.
particularly the change to the x and y of the gradient

So instead of

```
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.frame;
```

I change the x and y only ( width and hight doesn't causing this problem as far as I checked )

```
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(100,100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

And this is the result

[image]

Can anyone explain why this is happening and what are the possible solutions ?

What Im trying to achieve is this

[image]

And then masking it with the CAShapeLayer but then this problem happens

Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually `gradientLayer.frame = self.view.frame;` would be `gradientLayer.frame                 = self.view.bounds;, where `view`` is where it's the layer has been added. Remember, the coordinates for the frame are local to its superview/layer. For your issue, I think you want to change the frame of the shapelayer, not the frame of the gradient layer.

Comment: @Larme I know, but because the view is the size of the full screen it doesn't matter. and not effecting the problem

Answer (score 0):

change the shapelayer position, because gradient layer is fullscreen and shapelayer set center position and after you change the frame of gradient layer shapelayer also change with same position.

`layer.position = CGPointMake(30, 250);`

Comment: in the last picture (what Im trying to achieve ) the Gradient layer frame is CGRectMake(100,100, 300, 300); so its not full screen, after all the code above, if I try to update the position of both layers (  layer.position = self.view.center;
    gradientLayer.position = self.view.center;), the circle changes is location, but it still broken and not centered, so it doesn't work for me.